# Upsert (update+insert) in PostgreSQL via JDBC / JPA returning strange row-count

Tags: java, sql, postgresql, jpa, jdbc

I'm using an "upsert", and I need to know whether it has created a new row or not. 
The SQL is of the form:

```
update mytable set col1='value1' where (col2='value2');
insert into mytable select 'value1', 'value2' where not exists (select 1 from mytable where (col2='value2'));
```

If I run this in Postgres, it returns the count of affected rows for the 2nd statement. I.e. "1 row affected" if it does an insert, "0 rows affected" if it does an update. Which is what I'd expect.

Howevere if I run this over JDBC+JPA using a javax.persistence.Query object, I get the opposite behaviour: it returns 1 if it does an update, and 0 for an insert.

Is the Java behaviour reliable? 
I.e. can I code against that, or is it liable to change with future releases of the driver jar?

Is there a better way of writing the upsert so that I also get the information back about which operation it did?

Version details: I'm using PostgreSQL 9.1, Java 6, and the JDBC driver jar is postgresql-9.1-901.jdbc4.jar

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Are you running both statements in a single `executeUpdate()` call?

Comment: Yes I am. Two separate calls would presumably require two round-trips & be less efficient? Or should I not care?

Comment: Try to run two executeUpdate() calls and see if that gives you the correct update count. Also did you call `getMoreResults()` and `getUpdateCount()` repeatedly or only once?

Comment: Thanks. Using two executeUpdate() calls works. Though it's a shame to do two database calls, when one should cover it. I don't think getMoreResults and getUpdateCount are part of JPA.

Answer (score 1):

In Java you should be able to get back the row count for each statement, per the JDBC API documentation:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html#execute%28java.lang.String%29

The PostgreSQL docs provide an example where this is done in a plpgsql function:

http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/interactive/plpgsql-control-structures.html#PLPGSQL-ERROR-TRAPPING

Look for the merge_db() code sample.

Comment: I'm using the JPA interface: javax.persistence.Query.executeUpdate() http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/persistence/Query.html#executeUpdate()